# Submitting utf-8 to iso-8859-1 from server a to server b issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, utf-8

I don't really know how else to ask this, here is the scenario

On server A, it is in utf-8, I have a search form on server A which submits to server b which is in iso-8859-1. So when I submit a french word like "Carrières" by the time it gets to server B it comes out as "CarriÃ¨res".

I cannot change the encoding on server A or B, so is there a way to submit it from A and still get the right query on B? I can only edit server A files.

I tried converting it to html entities before submit but that comes out as is. I tried to add enctype to the form element (enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1") but it does not seem to work. I also tried the accept charset which seems to work on everything except IE (accept-charset="ISO-8859-1").

Is there anything else I can try other than those? Maybe something for IE only so i can use the accept charset method?

I can use jquery 1.4.2

Comment: You could write JavaScript to do the mapping from UTF-8 to Latin-1 yourself on IE?

Comment: @Rup If I write a funcction to map char to char and change the input value before submitting, the input value still shows the french char when submitted and the same thing happens. Could you go in a bit of detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote a little bit of server side script using java to solve this, did not find any JS solutions